# check a parent box by default and I need the other child boxes to be checked by default also

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I’m trying to check a parent box by default and I need the other child boxes to be checked by default also.
I try to write the following code, but it’s only check the parent box without the child boxes. As the screenshots below.

I believe that I miss something, can anyone help on this.

the Code:

```
                   <row>
        <label id="Cheackby_default">
          <text>
            <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    console.log('here');

                    // Change Log
                    // June 16 2016 - Remove the default check on the Update Map box on the header bar



                    {$("#ctl00_Main_ctl57_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_SelectColumnSelectCheckBox").prop("checked","true");}
                                        });
            </script> ]]>             
          </text>
               </label>
```

Example:
[image: Example]

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question directly in it. Please go read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You'll need to add a copy of the html. Highlight the area in the element-inspector, right-click and copy what's important (in this case it's those child-elements, pasting the whole table would be fine)